# D3 js not reacting to drag events in Android-Webview

Tags: android, d3.js, events, android-webview, pointer-events

I have an Android-webview including a d3.js (v5) graph.
Recently, the graph stopped responding to any events (drag, click, zoom) on several devices. I did not update the code base, so I guess it's related to an Android update?

I used Remote Webview debugging with chrome devtools but I did not manage to find the root cause.
I used `monitorEvents` to track the events. And the zoom & drag features started to work again until I used `unmonitorEvents`.

Any idea, on why would these events stop working suddenly and what is the side effect on `monitorEvents`?

Thanks for your help :)

**PS:** the webpage works without the webview.

[image: Hello World Graph]

The nodes are clickable, the whole graph can be moved or zoomed in and out.

**EDIT2:** **Found a first solution.**
After some search, I found this https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/pointer-events : the new events for mouse & touch actions. `monitorEvents` was doing an `addEventListener` for all `onpointer{something}` which was fixing the d3 code.

Right now, I am adding dump listeners to the root . That looks pretty ugly. What is the right action?